# Measure on free sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra

I know that there exist no measures (i.e. no non-negative, $\sigma$-additive, extended real-valued function) on a free $\sigma$-algebra with $\mathbb{N}$ generators. Where can I find a proof of that?

[Measure on free Boolean sigma-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357771/measure-on-free-boolean-sigma-algebras) addresses the issue, but I don't understand the argument, especially what $x_A$ represents.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x_A$ is defined as the meet of all $x_n, n \in A$ and all $\lnot x_n$ where $n \notin A$. Here $A$ is a subset of $\Bbb N$ and $\{x_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ is a countable set of generators for the Boolean $\sigma$-algebra. These meets exist as we have a $\sigma$-algebra… They are not $0$ as we have a *free* algebra.

The answer then argues that $x_A \land x_B = 0$ whenever $A \neq B$ in $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb N)$, which is correct and shows that the set $P:=\{x_A: A \subseteq \Bbb N\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family of size continuum (so uncountable and of uncountable cofinality) and this cannot happen in any measure algebra (as these are ccc: any set of pairwise disjoint elements is at most countable). So a lot of algebras cannot be made into a measure algebra. I assume (as is common in this field) that $x \neq 0$ will imply $\mu(x) >0$ so $\mu$ is strictly positive.

The argument to form $P$ is used also to show that an infinite $\sigma$-algebra cannot be countable. It’s pretty standard.

Comment: Thanks for replying. You probably meant that $x_A$ is the meet of all $x_n$, $n\in A$, and all $\neg x_n$, $n\in A$ (?)

Comment: Still, shoot me here, I don't see what $x_A$ represents. For example, say $A=\{1,2\}$. Then, taking the definition of $x_A$ in terms of meet, I have $x_{\{1,2\}}=x_1\wedge x_2\wedge\neg x_3\wedge\neg x_4,\ldots$ I don't get it.

Comment: @Hugh yes I mean $\land$ however you pronounce it.

Comment: @Hugh for $A=\1,2\}$ we indeed have $x_1\land x_2\land \lnot x_3\land \lnot x_4\ldots$, so a meet of infinitely many elements from the free $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that the only is point of this complicated expression is to guarantee the existence of a pairwise disjoint family of size of the continuum? Also, why is the construction of such a family only possible in a free $\sigma$-aglebra?

Comment: @Hugh yes it’s for the construction of such a family. That all these are nonzero is a consequence of the freeness. In a general $\sigma$-algebra there is no such guarantee.

Comment: OK, so a free sigma-algebra has no strictly positive, $\sigma$-additive probability measure. Does it have a finitely additive measure? This time, it should work...